# What is the best way to add a keyframe animation to a template using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am using Meteor/Blaze to build a web app and have a series of templates. In one of my templates I would like to animate the top nav bar and not have that animation take place in any other template that includes the bad.

I have a keyframe animation that I want to use in my Dashboard page. What is the best way for me to use the animation, and then either remove it in the onDestroy or just not have it be used in any other template?

I tried doing it with jQuery but I believe it is not possible with the syntax I used. Here is my code.

```
Template.Dashboard_page.onCreated(function homePageOnCreated() {

    $('.main-nav').css('animation' , 'navSlide 0.3s');

};
Template.Dashboard_page.onCreated(function homePageOnDestroyed() {

        $('.main-nav').css('animation' , '');

    };

    .main-nav {
      //css for the top bar
      }

    @keyframes navSlide{
      from {
      transform: translateY(-25%);
     }
      to {
      transform: translateY(0);
    }
  }
```

So what I tried doing was when the Dashboard template is created, to add the animation using .css() and then when it is destroyed to remove it using the same method.

This works for other CSS attributes like background-color, height etc. But not for 'animation'.

Could someone help assist me in finding a better solution?

Comment: Add/remove a class whose rule contains the animation.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `javascript` at Question appears to return expected result https://jsfiddle.net/ut3yms6e/